# How to make Excel not recognize the number as a date?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I import the number, but Excel recognizes it as a date.

Here is the formula:

`=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("http://iss.moex.com/iss/securities/SBER/dividends.xml?iss.meta=off");"//document//data//rows//row[1]/@value")`

Here is the raw data:

`<row secid="SBER" isin="RU0009029540" registryclosedate="2014-06-17" value="3.2" currencyid="RUB"/>`

My data format. Comma - separator of integer and fractional parts.

"3.2" Excel returns as date "03.02.2020".

How to import "3.2" as a number? Replacement does not help.

Comment: I can't easily test it in my locale, but just as an experiment =FILTERXML(SUBSTITUTE(WEBSERVICE(<URL>),"3.2","3,200"),"//document//data//rows//row[1]/@value") correctly gives 3200 so it looks as if substitution should work?

Comment: If I try at my location then it retrieves a number `3.2`. Conversion to date might be occurring due to the location specific date settings on your computer. On my computer they are "English (United States)".

Comment: @TomSharpe, after using SUBSTITUTE:
<?xml version=""1,0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>

Original:
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>

The FILTERXML function does not recognize this xml.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij, I can’t change the language settings on the computer.

Comment: @TomSharpe, it works after two SUBSTITUTE :)

`=ФИЛЬТР.XML(
ПОДСТАВИТЬ(
ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ВЕБСЛУЖБА("http://iss.moex.com/iss/securities/"&A$3&"/dividends.xml?iss.meta=off");".";",");"1,0";"1.0");"//document//data//rows//row["&СТРОКА()-2&"]/@value")`

Comment: Can you try to add an apostrophe to the resultant raw data? i.e. =SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("http://iss.moex.com/iss/securities/SBER/dividends.xml?iss.meta=off");"//document//data//rows//row[1]/@value"),"value=""","value=""'")